# Creating specific enumaration inside LaTeX table

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate, cell

I´m wondering if creating a LaTeX table that allows for specific enumeration inside one of its cells is possible. For instance, something like this:

[image]

I have tried using certain environments, but I didn´t reach any solution. The option of using the `description` environment is an option, but it produces a space that I do not particularly like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{3D2B1F}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{myGreen}}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Contenidos y criterios de evaluación a conseguir en esta UD.}
\label{tab:Saberes basicos}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}

\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Contenidos}} & \textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Criterios de evaluación}} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{itemize}
\item Importancia de elegir un sistema de referencia para poder describir el movimiento de una partícula. 
\item Variables cinemáticas en función del tiempo en los distintos movimientos de la partícula (posición, desplazamiento, velocidad, aceleración, etc), con o sin fuerzas externas. Obtener unas magnitudes a partir de otras usando el análisis matemático. Resolución de situaciones reales relacionadas con la física y el entorno cotidiano, aplicando el cálculo vectorial. 
\item Variables que influyen en un movimiento rectilíneo y circular: magnitudes y unidades empleadas. Deducción de las ecuaciones del movimiento. Movimientos cotidianos que presentan estos tipos de trayectoria.
\item Relación de la trayectoria de un movimiento compuesto con las magnitudes que lo describen. Visualización gráfica de las funciones correspondientes.
\item Comprensión de la diferencia entre sistemas de referencia inerciales y sistemas de referencia no inerciales para describir de forma cualitativa el movimiento relativo de los cuerpos en situaciones de la vida cotidiana y para resolver problemas sencillos en una sola dimensión en sistemas de referencia inerciales haciendo uso del principio de relatividad de Galileo.
\end{itemize}

 & 

\begin{description}
    \item[1.1] Aplicar leyes científicas para analizar fenómenos cinemáticos.
    \item[1.2] Resolver problemas de situaciones cotidianas, expresando adecuadamente los resultados.
     \item[1.3] Identificar situaciones del entorno cotidiano y buscar soluciones.
    \item[2.1] Formular y verificar hipótesis como respuesta a problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas para validar las hipótesis.
     \item[2.2] Formular y verificar hipótesis como respuesta a problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas para validar las hipótesis.
      \item[2.3]\hspace{0,26cm}Formular y verificar hipótesis como respuesta a problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas para validar las hipótesis.
    \item[3.1]\hspace{0,26cm}Utilizar correctamente las unidades y su notación, prestando especial atención a las diferentes unidades de velocidad y tiempo.
    \item[3.3] Emplear diferentes formatos para interpretar y expresar información cinemática, extrayendo lo más relevante durante la resolución de un problema.
\end{description}

\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pleas show us, what you try so far. What table environment you use? Do you employ `enumitem` package?  It will be very helpful that you provide MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: No, I do not use ```enumitem``` package.

Comment: Thank you for MWE, but unfortunately is not complete. Missed are some packages. Please test it before publishing here.. With enumitem package is simple to customize lists in table ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For above table I use `tabularray` and `enumitem` packages. The firs enable simple and short table code, the second customize list in column:

**Edit:**
Ups, I didn't load last version of table code. Now corrected:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, 
            hmargin={3cm,2cm}, vmargin={3cm,2cm}
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % can be simple customized
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Contenidos y criterios de evaluación a conseguir en esta UD.}
    \label{tab:Saberes basicos}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{2}{X[j, font=\sffamily]}},
\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{2}{X[j, font=\sffamily]}},
             column{1} = {rightsep=12pt},
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries, fg=myGreen, rowsep =7pt},
                row{2} = {abovesep=7pt, belowsep=-2pt},
               stretch = -1,
               measure = vbox,
             }
    \toprule[green]
Contenidos  &   Criterios de evaluación     \\
    \midrule[green]
\begin{itemize}[nosep, itemsep=0.5ex, leftmargin=*]
\item Importancia de elegir un sistema de referencia para poder describir el movimiento de una partícula.
\item Variables cinemáticas en función del tiempo en los distintos movimientos de la partícula (posición, desplazamiento, velocidad, aceleración, etc), con o sin fuerzas externas. Obtener unas magnitudes a partir de otras usando el análisis matemático. Resolución de situaciones reales relacionadas con la física y el entorno cotidiano, aplicando el cálculo vectorial.
\item Variables que influyen en un movimiento rectilíneo y circular: magnitudes y unidades empleadas. Deducción de las ecuaciones del movimiento. Movimientos cotidianos que presentan estos tipos de trayectoria.
\item Relación de la trayectoria de un movimiento compuesto con las magnitudes que lo describen. Visualización gráfica de las funciones correspondientes.
\item Comprensión de la diferencia entre sistemas de referencia inerciales y sistemas de referencia no inerciales para describir de forma cualitativa el movimiento relativo de los cuerpos en situaciones de la vida cotidiana y para resolver problemas sencillos en una sola dimensión en sistemas de referencia inerciales haciendo uso del principio de relatividad de Galileo.
\end{itemize}   &   \begin{enumerate}[label = 1.\arabic*, itemsep=0.5ex, leftmargin=*]
                \item   Aplicar leyes científicas para analizar fenómenos cinemáticos.
                \item   Resolver problemas de situaciones cotidianas, expresando adecuadamente los resultados.
                \item   Identificar situaciones del entorno cotidiano y buscar soluciones.
                    \end{enumerate}
                    \begin{enumerate}[label = 2.\arabic*, itemsep=0.5ex, leftmargin=*]
                \item   Formular y verificar hipótesis como respuesta a problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas para validar las hipótesis.
                \item   Formular y verificar hipótesis como respuesta a problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas para validar las hipótesis.
                \item   \hspace{0,26cm}Formular y verificar hipótesis como respuesta a problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas para validar las hipótesis.
                    \end{enumerate}
                    \begin{enumerate}[label = 3.\arabic*, itemsep=0.5ex, leftmargin=*]
                \item   Utilizar correctamente las unidades y su notación, prestando especial atención a las diferentes unidades de velocidad y tiempo.
                \item   Emplear diferentes formatos para interpretar y expresar información cinemática, extrayendo lo más relevante durante la resolución de un problema.
                    \end{enumerate} \\
    \bottomrule[green]
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```